# Partial Multi byte character error in ssas - ORA 29275

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, ssas-tabular

Could you please help me out, i am getting ORA-29275 error while processing SSAS tabular model.

I am extracting data from oracle to SSAS tabular model, i have already changed the culture and collation properties in the SSAS code itself, but no luck.

Please let me know the exact solution to it.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this error is specific to SQL Server / SSAS Tabular. Most likely, you need to change the query or fix the data in your Oracle DB to avoid this issue. See for example: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_29275_partial_multibyte_character.htm (first Google hit for that error message)

Comment: Have tried doing that, by using a convert function and it works as well, some characters converted but those of some different unicode did not get convert and showing as a ? in SSDT.